# How to set email as optional in devise and use recoverable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Email is optional in devise and recoverable is on:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :confirmable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :trackable,
    :registerable

  def confirm_if_no_email
    skip_confirmation! if email.blank?
  end

  def email_required?
    false
  end
end
```

```rb
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.reset_password_keys = [:username]
end
```

But I've got this bug when I submit the username of a user that has no email address:
SMTP To address may not be blank.

I've been able to fix it by editing devise controllers. Is there a simpler way to do it? If not, tell me so I can add it to devise functionality.

Answer (score -1):

By overriding `send_reset_password_instructions_notification` method you can skip sending email:

```rb
# in your User class
def send_reset_password_instructions_notification
  return if email.blank?
  super
end
```

Also this is dirty hack, though perhaps you know.

Comment: However, I cannot inform the user of what happened. The user thinks the email actually was sent.